# accessing an action in a controller from a class method in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, backgroundworker

So I have a background job that accessess a module I made that looks like this:

```
module Workers::MultPackingSlipWorker

  extend Workers::BaseWorker

  def self.mult_packing_slip(orders_array, tracker_id)
    orders = orders_array.split('-').map { |e| ::Print::Order.find(e) }
    receipt_template = Print::Orders::OrderReceipt.new(orders, tracker_id)
    pdf_receipt_output = receipt_template.gen_pdf
    Manage::Store::OrdersController.mult_packing_slip(pdf_receipt_output)
  end

end
```

currenty I have a controller class, and a background job that accesses the class method must_packing_slip, basically I need a way to bridge between the two methods listed below.  The two attempts i've tried are commented out with their outcome also listed.  There has to be some way to access that stupid send_file method from a background process.  Any ideas or suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks.

```
class Manage::Store::OrdersController < Manage::Store::BaseController

 def self.mult_packing_slip(pdf_receipt_output)
  @pdf_receipt_output = pdf_receipt_output

   # redirect_to path_to_pack_mult => no method redirect_to for Manage::Store::OrdersController

   # pack_mul => no method pack_mult for Manage::Store::OrdersController

 end

 def pack_mult
   send_file(@pdf_receipt_output, :type => Mime::PDF, :disposition => 'inline')
 end

end
```

Comment: Why do you want to access `send_file` from a background job? The method is used to return something to the client but the background job has no client. For the same reason you shouldn't access a controller from a background service...it doesn't make any sense. If you need to share code between a controller and a background job you probably want to create a class for it.

Comment: basically I want the user to click something, start a process (namely, start generating a large pdf) and when the process is through I want them to be redirected to where the pdf is.  is there a way to do this in a background process, so that the app is still usable while the pdf is being generated?